# jQuery 1.5.1 vs 1.4.4 weirdness

Tags: jquery, css

I have been getting some weird errors when I upgrade jQuery from 1.4.4 to 1.5.1. Maybe you guys can explain what I need to change or why the new version is not working.

In 1.4.4 I have the following code

```
<div class="navlink home" data-link="home">
    <span class="top">Home</span>
</div>
<div id="index-03">
</div>
<div class="navlink resume" data-link="resume">
    <span class="top">Resume</span>
</div>
<div id="index-05">
</div>
<div id="index-06">
</div>
<div class="navlink portfolio" data-link="portfolio">
    <span class="bottom">Portfolio</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".navlink").hover( 
    function () { 
        $(this).delay(100).animate({backgroundPosition: "-100% 0"}, 400);
        $(this).find("span").css("textDecoration","underline");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).queue("fx", []);
        $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: "0% 0%"}, 400);
        $(this).find("span").css("textDecoration","none");
    }
);
```

Which works just fine.

but when I switch jQuery versions by changing this line in my header from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The above code quits animating and the background image just disappears.

Here is a jsFiddle that shows what's happening just change the jQuery version on the side between 1.4.4 and 1.5.1

http://jsfiddle.net/fUXZ4/ -- 1.4.4

http://jsfiddle.net/3APCd/ -- 1.5.1

Here is a video of exactly what is happening to me: http://img.zobgib.com/2011-03-07_1905.swf

Comment: Not for me. Make sure you click run again after you change the version.  It doesn't work for me on a mac with Safari 5.0.3, FireFox 3.6.10, or Google Chrome 9.0.597.107.

Comment: Yes I understand it works for jQuery 1.4.1 but not for jQuery 1.5.1

Comment: I am using the exact same version of chrome as you and the hover slide thing does not work at all for me.  Will you try clicking the 1.5.1 version I link in the question now and tell me if it works

Comment: you are misunderstanding jsfiddle you if you reload the page you will get version 1.4.4 again

Comment: @zobgib: As i misunderstood jsfiddly (drop down list not reverting as to when reload) i removed my comments to clear the path. I can just confirm it doesnt work with 1.5.1 with firefox (latest) on osx.

Comment: Seems like there's a couple issues. First with `mouseenter/mouseleave`. If I strip it down to nothing but a log: `console.log(e.type)`, the event is firing only on the first element matched. If I switch to `mouseover/mouseout` (which you don't necessarily want to use) the handlers fire, but the animations still don't work.

Comment: @patrick I am not sure I understand what you are saying.  There should only be one element that matches the 'this' selector for the .click() function. What else would match?

Comment: @zobgib: I mean only the first element matched by `.navlink` was receiving the event, but now I see it has something more to do with positioning. If I change the `left` to `0, 200px, 400px` for each respective image, (and `top:0`), the events fire, though the animation is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably (although i didn't check) jquery 1.5 is less tolerant of double numeric values, this is from the `.animate()` docs:

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value

I changed your animation to animate `backgroundPositionX` (you weren't changing the y values anyway), which will then be a *single* numeric value.

Although this seems to be both an intolerance + a jquery bug, because that fix alone doesn't play well with 1.5.1, I had to also remove the `position:absolute`, and then it plays nice:

http://jsfiddle.net/fUXZ4/2/

Maybe try floating and spacing the div's to achieve the same look.

I would also recommend some code changes, like chaining `$(this)` all the way through, and using `.stop(true,false)` instead of your `.queue()` call.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much. And what is wrong with $(this). Mine worked without removing the absolute positioning.

Comment: @zobgib, nothing is wrong with it, but every time you execute `$(this)`, jquery creates a new jquery object, which takes time. If you chain all your calls, you only need to create that object once. compare the code in my answer to http://jsfiddle.net/fUXZ4/3/ I only call `$(this)` once in each function. It also makes the code shorter

Comment: Also just for the sake of info backgroundPositionX does not exist for firefox but because I am changing the X only using backgroundPosition with only one value works fine. i.e. 'backgroundPosition: "-100%"'. And if you don't mind explaining why stop() is better than the queue()

Comment: @zobgib, `.queue()` is a general queue manipulating function, so if you use it to clear the queue you dont really control in what way the current animation is stopped, `.stop()` is made to stop the current queue, so it makes the code more understandable, and more importantly it is designed specifically to clear the queue (as opposed to a general queue manipulation function) so you can control in what way you do so (see the docs for stop, you can pass in different parameters for different behaviour)